# How to check if record has been inserted into database table?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I check insert success in my code?

I tried to test my code below, but it doesn't work. It just returns *insert* every time.

```
<?PHP
   include("connect.php");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO details (name , month , description) 
            SELECT name , month , description 
            FROM details_temporary WHERE id = 'xxxxxx'";

   $dbQuery = mysql_query($sql);

   if($dbQuery) {
      echo "insert";
   }
   else {
      echo "not insert";
   }
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Good lord... No mysql!

Comment: This code is correct.  If you are doing an `INSERT` query (which you are), then `mysql_query` will return a boolean.  So, how do you figure it "doesn't work"?  Why wouldn't it return `"insert"` every time?  Is this query supposed to be failing?  What do you expect this code to do?  Did you check to see if rows were inserted?

Comment: to - Rocket Hazmat # it's echo insert but not have data in row.

Comment: One method I use is `if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){ echo "Exists"; }`

Comment: that's because you're using `mysql_` instead of `mysqli_` which you should be using

Comment: how can i apply my code to mysqli_ ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're really going to have to make an effort with this. I'm not going to comment for hours, and/or post an answer, in "HOPING" it's going to work for you. Just Google what I gave you, that will get you started. Good luck with that.

Comment: Plus, there's already been an [**answer given below**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21094908/1415724) that should theoretically work. Work with that.

Comment: You can use PDO statements, check documentation: 
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 1):

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new
> code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php)
> They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation
> process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See
> the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?
> Learn about [prepared
> statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead,
> and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or
> [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this
> [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will
> help you decide which.

An example using the MySQLi functionality is below:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database_name');

$sql = "INSERT INTO details (name, month, description) VALUES ('Alex', 'October', 'My Birthday')";
$result= $mysqli -> query($sql);
$affected = $mysqli -> affected_rows;

if($affected == 1){
   echo 'Inserted';
}else{
   echo 'Did not insert';
}
```

Comment: Prepared statements are where it's at!  You should be using them :-)

Comment: Yeah totally agree. Just wanted to get something down. Will update the example.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use MySQL functions, they're deprecated and insecure, look in to using MySQLi or PDO.

Secondly, MySQL will only return an error if it failed, so you can just simply run:

```
if (!$dbQuery) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

This will die and print the error if it was unsuccessful.

If you want to check further, you could check mysqli_insert_id() as this will only be set if the query was successful (will only work for inserts, not updates, etc).

Comment: Using MySQL is fine, using the mysql_* functions is however a no no. You're using MySQL even when using MySQLi or PDO if that's the chosen database structure (I know you're talking about mysql_*, I'm just making it clear to OP so he doesn't thing he has to switch to PostgreSql or something like that).

Comment: I know but someone could get confused :) (Updated)

Answer (score 0):

You are using INSERT FROM SELECT and if the select has no result then it will insert nothing and still have true in $dbQuery.

Use [mysql_affected_rows.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) : Get number of affected rows in previous MySQL operation

mysql_* functions are deprecated as of php 5.5

**If** you are working on a new project and NOT changing an old one, it's best to use pdo/mysqli etc.